# MBeanOperationInfo and MBeanAttributeInfo meta data?

Tags: java, encryption, jmx

I have written a JMX interface for one of our applications. Another application then connects and allows the user to see various state related attributes / invoke operations remotely via this management tool. I stumbled across a small bug where our database connection settings are being exposed over JMX, with the password unencrypted. I would like to tag the attributes / operations that should be obfuscated with some flag, but it doesnt appear as though the MBeanAttributeInfo or MBeanOperationInfo objects support adding any user defined values exception for name and description. I suppose I could delimit the description field like

```
String desc = getAttrDesc() + ";" + getIsObfuscated();
```

But I dont like this approach very much. The question then is, is there a better way to provide arbitrary key value pairs to an attribute / operation info object, or the Dynamic MBean itself? It doesnt have to be on the info objects themselves, just as long as I can match them up on the management tool side. Any insight would be appreciated.

Just for clarification, when I construct the MBeanOperationInfo (leaving out the attributes for the sake of example) I do so like this:

```
        LinkedList<MBeanOperationInfo> opperInfos = new LinkedList<MBeanOperationInfo>();
        for (Method m : m_InstObj.getMethods()) {
            InstrumentedOperation anno = m.getAnnotation(InstrumentedOperation.class);
            String desc = anno.description();
            opperInfos.add(new MBeanOperationInfo(desc, m));
        }

        m_Operations = new MBeanOperationInfo[opperInfos.size()];
        int I = 0;
        for (MBeanOperationInfo info : opperInfos) {
            m_Operations[I] = info;
            I++;
        }
```

I would like the InstrumentedOperation annotation to have a field for obfuscated that I can use like this:

```
anno.obfuscated(); // <- retreives a boolean set as a compile time constant on the annotation
```

and be able to include this value in the Info object.

Then on the receiving side I do this:

```
MBeanOperationInfo[] operInfos = conn.getMBeanInfo(name).getOperations();

for (MBeanOperationInfo info : operInfos) {
    String propName = getPropNameFromInfo(info.getName());
    if (!uniqueSettings.contains(propName)) {
        // this setting hasn't been handled, get the getters and setters and make the method map
        String getter = getGetterForSetting(operInfos, info.getName());
        String setter = getSetterForSetting(operInfos, info.getName());
        Object value = conn.invoke(name, getter, new Object[] {}, new String[] {});
        if (getter != null && setter != null) {
            SettingMethodMap map = new SettingMethodMap(name.getKeyProperty("type"), propName, info.getName(), setter, getter, value);
            uniqueSettings.add(propName);
            m_Settings.add(map);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I would like to be able to retreive the key value pair  through some mechanism, so I would know that I need to handle this field different and obfuscate it in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [javax.management.DescriptorKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/DescriptorKey.html).

For example, using a code sample that I adapted for this, using a [standard mbean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/StandardMBean.html):

"Obfuscated" annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import javax.management.DescriptorKey;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Obfuscated {
  @DescriptorKey("obfuscated")
  boolean value() default true;
}
```

MBean interface:

```
public interface LoginMBean {
  String getName();

  @Obfuscated
  String getPassword();
}
```

MBean implementation:

```
public class Login implements LoginMBean {
  private final String user;
  private final String password;

  public Login(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
  }

  @Override public String getName() { return user; }

  @Override public String getPassword() { return password; }
}
```

Some code to register the MBean and browse its information:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import javax.management.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
      ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("com.mydomain", "type", "login");
      server.registerMBean(
        new StandardMBean(new Login("John Doe", "password"), LoginMBean.class), mbeanName);
      MBeanInfo mbeanInfo = server.getMBeanInfo(mbeanName);
      MBeanAttributeInfo[] attrs = mbeanInfo.getAttributes();
      for (MBeanAttributeInfo attr: attrs) {
        Descriptor desc = attr.getDescriptor();
        boolean obfuscated = false;
        if (desc.getFieldValue("obfuscated") != null) {
          obfuscated = (Boolean) desc.getFieldValue("obfuscated");
        }
        if (obfuscated) System.out.printf("field '%s' is obfuscated%n", attr.getName());
        else {
          Object value = server.getAttribute(mbeanName, attr.getName());
          System.out.printf("value of field '%s' is '%s'%n", 
            attr.getName(), value == null ? "null" : value.toString());
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, the output after running Main:

```
value of field 'Name' is 'John Doe'
field 'Password' is obfuscated
```

Comment: This looks promising! I will give this a shot. I think ill have to do this by constructing the MBean Info objects with the constructor overload that takes a descriptor, but otherwise I think it should work out nicely

Comment: Accepted. Worked out great using the constructor overload that provides the descriptor. Thanks @Lolo